# select statement from mssql in Perl file

Tags: perl

Simply, I use Perl to select a value from mssql database and print it.

here is my code:

```
my $serverName = "Alaa";
    my $database="blasti2b2";
    my $user="i2b2blast";
    my $pass="demouser";

    my $dsn  = "Provider=sqloledb;Trusted Connection=yes;";
    $dsn .= "Server=$serverName;Database=$database";
    my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:ADO:$dsn",$user,$pass,{ RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 1}) || die "Database connection not made: $DBI::errstr";

    my $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT DatabaseVersion FROM BlastDatabaseDim WHERE DatabaseName = $db_name");
    $sql->execute();
    my @row
    @row = $sql->fetchrow_array
    my $DatabaseVersion= $row[0];
    print "$DatabaseVersion\n";
```

I have error in $DatabaseVersion, $db_name, and @row.

Any right way please?

+

How to check Null value?
I try:

```
if ($DatabaseVersion eq undef)
if ($DatabaseVersion == undef)
if ($DatabaseVersion eq '')
if ($DatabaseVersion eq "")
```

all give me an error.
Thanks

Comment: It should be `$sql->fetchrow_array();` not just `$sql->fetchrow_array`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change at least these lines:

```
    my $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT DatabaseVersion FROM BlastDatabaseDim WHERE DatabaseName = ?");
    $sql->execute($db_name);
    my @row = $sql->fetchrow_array();
```

Comment: So? What is update_blastdb.pl? It is/should be your code after all.

Comment: "$db_name" was defined in a block. I define it globally. It is working now. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please chek the second part in my post? thanks

Comment: `if (defined $value)
{
  Do that
}
else
{
  Do this
}`

Comment: Any reasonable Perl Tutorial would have given you this.